# Set multiple dots in responsive screen android

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design, dynamic-programming

[image: this is My first show layout without set any values]

[image: this is my value set layout]

I want to set dots between circle icon and location icon in both layout with responsive in all devices.Circle icon should stick with Home Location `TextView` and Location icon stick with Work Location `TextView` in both screen.

I have added dots image between both icon but after set text it can not be responsive because of fix dots images. Then i have added dots by java code like this.

```
 private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
 private TextView[] dots;
 dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);

    private void addLayoutDots() {
    dots = new TextView[7];

    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(getActivity());
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setHeight(40);
        dots[i].setTextSize(20);   
      dots[i].setTextColor(CommonUtils.getColor(getActivity()
                ,R.color.colorBrown));
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);

    }

}
```

its xml like this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvFSLTHomeWork"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivSource"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/ll_padding_setting"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_source_map_brown_48px" />

                <MyPackage.VectorTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFSLTHomeLoc"
                    style="@style/tvSettingStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ivSource"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivSource"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/et_hint_fslt_home_loc"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_home_white_48px" 
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivDest"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvFSLTHomeLoc"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ll_padding_setting"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location_on_orange_48px"  

                    />



                <MyPackage.VectorTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFSLTWorkLoc"
                    style="@style/tvSettingStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvFSLTHomeLoc"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivDest"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/et_hint_fslt_work_loc"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ivDest"
                    app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_work_white_48px"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dotsLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/ivSource"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_above="@id/tvFSLTWorkLoc"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

But using this i can't achieve responsive layout. Please give me your valuable suggestions. Thank you